# Installing multiple msi files with powershell

Tags: powershell, logging, installation

I'm installing windows to multiple machines 2-10 in a month. Am looking for an easy automated process where I just run the process on the local machines before they are joining the domain, for new users.

I want to put my log files nearby where my script runs also, I want to make an array for the file names where are the .msi files name is also the drivers are in the same folder as the script.

```
$id = @('r17rw02w','r17rw11w','n2xst05w')
foreach ($xyz in $id){

$MSI = '$PSScriptRoot\$xyz.msi'

$DateStamp = get-date -Format yyyyMMddTHHmmss
$logFile = "$PSScriptRoot\$MSI-$DateStamp.log"

$MSIArguments = @(
    "/i"
    "`"$MSI`""
    "/passive"
    "/norestart"
    "/L*v"
    $logFile
)
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $MSIArguments -Wait -NoNewWindow
}
```

Or should I run it as a single package for easier installation with `/progress` to see the taskbar where is the installation heading? Also i'm going to use runas to autmaticly runing as admin.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier/more efficient to update your system image?

Comment: Does your code have any errors or are you rather asking for our opinion wether this is a good way to do it? In our company we have a software deployment tool for initial installation and keeping all the PCs up to date...

Comment: Due to new IT security, I can't modify the image back in the days I used to do that.@Bill_Stewart ...